# Olivetti history and/or coffee table book

Tags: designers, education, history

I'm a big style fan of the company Olivetti, I mainly know them for their typewriters (Lettera 22 and 32 are my favorites) but doing a little more research I found some amazing print ads ( https://www.itsnicethat.com/articles/olivetti-form-and-function-ica-310516 ).

As far as I can google search, there hasn't been a book about the company and it's design influences (in my ideal world it would be a big coffee table books with full page reproductions of those ads). My question: Does such a book exist? Has their ever been an Olivetti book covering their history and design styling/attitudes?

Answer (score 1):

There's a 1952 document from MOMA called "Olivetti, design in industry". You can find it here https://www.moma.org/documents/moma_catalogue_2741_300159054.pdf

There are some covers and posters, but unfortunately the PDF is black & white.

Answer (score 0):

Not strictly Olivetti but there is a book published by Moleskine about Olivetti's lead graphic designer Giovanni Pintori. It has at least one full color page ad for Lettera.

A review is found here:
https://www.foldmagazine.com/moleskine-bookshelf-giovanni-pintori